# Angular Pipe Replace character

Tags: angular

I have written a pipe in Angular to replace the character `|` with a `,`.

```
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Name|with|pipes';
}
```

The desired output is `Name,with,pipes`, but I am seeing it as `,N,a,m,e,|,w,i,t,h,|,p,i,p,e,s,`

Here's the code for the pipe:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({name: 'replace'})
export class ReplacePipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: string, strToReplace: string, replacementStr: string): string {

    if(!value || ! strToReplace || ! replacementStr)
    {
      return value;
    }

 return value.replace(new RegExp(strToReplace, 'g'), replacementStr);
  }
}
```

Here's the code on [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sbt1lt). How can I fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you need to do it like this or change you pipe

```
{{ name | replace : '[|]' : ',' }}
```

or yes, double escape like the others suggest.  The clue is, is a specific meaning under regex already, so you can't use it directly

Answer (score 8):

The character `|` is interpreted as the alternation character in the regular expression. You can escape the search string with the help of the method given in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3561711/1009922):

```
escapeStr(str) {
  return str.replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&');
}
```

The resulting string is then used to create the regular expression in the pipe `transform` method:

```
return value.replace(new RegExp(this.escapeStr(strToReplace), 'g'), replacementStr);
```

With this technique, the template markup doesn't have to be aware of the implementation details, and can use the pipe normally:

```
{{ name | replace : '|' : ',' }}
```

See [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xi9arg?file=app/app.component.ts) for a demo.

Answer (score 3):

Apparently, you need to escape the character in your html when calling the pipe.

In your `app.component.html` try write this line:

```
{{ name | replace : '\\|' : ',' }}
```

And it should work.
([stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sbt1lt) updated here)